# Mostrar elementos hijos html y js

Tags: javascript, html

Me gustaria saber como puedo solo mostrar los elementos hijos con javascript por ejemplo.

```
<div class="row">
    <span class="red">66 
        <span>22 </span>
    </span>
    <span class="green">24
        <span class="blue" style="color: #000;">82 </span>
    </span>
    <span class="green">10 
        <span class="blue" style="color: #000;">1 </span>
    </span>
    <span class="red">69 
        <span>80 </span>
    </span>
    <span class="red">12 
        <span class="green" style="color: #000;">11 </span>
    </span>
 </div>
```

Me gustaria solo mostrar los "span" hijos

Tengo hecho algo así pero no funciona y no se como darle forma

```
function myFunction6() {
var foo = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (var i = 0; i < foo.children.length; i++) {
        console.log(foo.children[i].tagName);
}
}
```

Gracias

Comment: Un concejo: Usa nombres representativos en tus funciones. Te ahorra tiempo a la hora de acordarte q función era. Tanto para ti como para los q lean tu código.

Comment: si los span que estan dentro de los span,

Comment: Es que el problema lo daban así sorry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es quedarte sólo con los `span` que están dentro de otro `span` en el div con clase `.row`, te recomendaría que usases un selector diferente de `getElementsByTagName`. Por ejemplo, sería más conveniente usar [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

A esa función le pasas un selector como los de CSS y te devolverá todos los elementos que cumplen esa condición. Así por ejemplo, con el selector `.row > span > span` lo que vas a obtener son todos los elementos `span` que son hijos directos de otro `span` y que estén dentro de `.row`. Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
function myFunction6() {
  var foo = document.querySelectorAll('.row > span > span');
  for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    console.log(foo[i].tagName + " " + foo[i].textContent);
  }
}

myFunction6()
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span class="red">66 
    <span>22 </span>
  </span>
  <span class="green">24
    <span class="blue" style="color: #000;">82 </span>
  </span>
  <span class="green">10 
    <span class="blue" style="color: #000;">1 </span>
  </span>
  <span class="red">69 
    <span>80 </span>
  </span>
  <span class="red">12 
    <span class="green" style="color: #000;">11 </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Vale es perfecta esta solución , muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

Se puede hacer con css, prueba con éste código... Los `span` hijos són de color verde.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("span").each(function(){
    if($(this).parent().is("span")){
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div > span {
  color:red
  }
  span > span{
  color:green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <span class="red">66 
        <span>22 </span>
    </span>
    <span class="green">24
        <span class="blue">82 </span>
    </span>
    <span class="green">10 
        <span class="blue" >1 </span>
    </span>
    <span class="red">69 
        <span>80 </span>
    </span>
    <span class="red">12 
        <span class="green">11 </span>
    </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: No es eso exactamente lo que necesito, necesito solo quedarme con los span que estan dentro del span es decir el valor